# What does "white crackers" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading *The Round House* by Louise Erdrich. I've came across to this expression and I know it normally is a racial slur about white people. The book is about Native Americans and the term is used by one, but I feel like the author meant a whole different thing and used it for an object rather than a person. He says people sit and gape at this round white cracker. Is it the sacrament? For context, the tribe is Ojibwa and the narrator is in the hospital with his parents and calls his aunt and her husband to let them know but they won't answer. Here is the paragraph it's in:

> But there was no answer. So I knew my aunt
>   had taken Edward up to adore the sacrament, which got them out of the
>   house on Sunday nights. He said that while Clemence adored the sacrament,
>   he meditated on how it could be possible that humans had evolved
>   out of apes only *to sit gaping at a round **white cracker***. Uncle Edward was
>   a science teacher.

Comment: It's referring to a communion wafer, a edible  wheat cracker used in a religious rite in the Roman Catholic Church.

Comment: Thank you, so it is really a cracker.

Comment: This is what it looks like: https://media.famigliacristiana.it/2016/5/eucarestia2_1773658.jpg - also here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramental_bread

Comment: In the Anglican churches too, where it is called a "[wafer](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wafer)" see **2.1**.

Comment: When my wife and I eat round wheat crackers and cheese while watching the TV, it is my little joke to pick one up and solemnly intone "body of Christ". My wife was raised Catholic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wafer is said to be 'transubstantiated' into Christ's flesh...

[image]